# Application freezes when call "scanf" function

Tags: objective-c, scanf

There is a simple hackerrank task, where I stuck on getting input phase.
Input code is simple (I'm using Objective-C)

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  @autoreleasepool {

    NSUInteger t;
    scanf("%ld",&t);

    int n,m,s;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < t) {
      scanf("%d %d %d",&n,&m,&s);
      printf("%d  n=%d m=%d s=%d \n",i,n,m,s);
      i++;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

But on a big test case with t=100, this small program freezes on step 33.
It looks like problem is in scanf function call,but cannot find it.

Here is [testcase](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2AoU1a6IHPOWHdyN1RUckVoNUU/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Without seeing your input there's not much help to offer. Just make sure each line has three numbers separated by a space and terminated with a newline.

Comment: @rmaddy I add testcase to google drive.

Comment: Your code appears to work, you'll need to add more details of how you are running it, what you've tried in the debugger, etc. for people to help you.

Comment: Use plain Xcode run, nothing special.

Comment: I tested your code in Xcode 7.3.1. You do not show how you attach your input file to `stdin`, I simply added a call to `freopen` to handle this. The code works. If it always stops on the 33rd iteration place a breakpoint which breaks only after that many hits, then when the breakpoint fires step through your code examining all the variables etc. and see what happens. If you need more help provide more detail, say what the debugger reveals, etc. - edit your question and add the details. People can only guess with the information provided so far. HTH